# Why does this database entry not appear in phpmyadmin, but will return the data when queried?

Tags: python, mysql, database, mariadb

I cannot get my python code to create a database entry in phpMyAdmin, but when I request to fetch the data, it will return the data, however if I change the data inputted, it will then return that data but not the old value from the database. Here is my code:

```
import mariadb

# connection parameters
conn_params= {
    "user" : "xxx",
    "password" : "xxx",
    "host" : "xxx",
    "database" : "xxx"
}

# Establish a connection
connection= mariadb.connect(**conn_params)

cursor= connection.cursor()

# Populate countries table  with some data
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO to_scan(ID, URL, SECTION) VALUES (?,?,?)",(4, "Test.com", "Berlin"))
print("retrieve")
# retrieve data
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM to_scan")

# print content
row= cursor.fetchall()
print(*row, sep=' ')

# free resources
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Returns `(1, 'http://www.testurl.com', 'amateur') (4, 'Test.com', 'Berlin')`
but there is no sign of the number 4 entry in the database, and if I change the value of the insert query it will then list that value, but not the one previously submitted, what am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: You don't call `commit()` after inserting the data in your Python code.

Comment: Oh my word, how silly of me. It works! Thank you for your time Bill